# Help me find the 6-letter password!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, password

## Help me find the password!

All stories in this puzzle are fictions.

Once I was checking my old notes, and found a small chest with a 6-letter lock and 4 strange papers.

**Paper #1**

| inventor | a | b | d | h | t | m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s | 0 | 1 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 9 |
| o | 3 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 7 |
| a | 4 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 8 | 9 |
| e | 7 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 2 |
| i | 4 | 2 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 5 |
| y | 6 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 2 |

```
qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl;
zxcvbnm,./
```

**Paper #2**, a story

On the first day he thought about reversing words, or move one character from the end to the beginning; but soon he abandoned this unbrilliant idea. On the second day, he looked at his table, and suddenly found something. An inventor wouldn't let any ideas go away. Finally, inspired by an old machine, he invented the encoder on the fifth day, but it's extremely *dangerous*.

**Paper #3**, unreadable characters

```
ABC
COMPOSE YEAR
´Ã£óEÕ´CDCE×Ç´BöB÷ÖBs"ÖBsróDBò÷Âä2æ2w§£2òô2ò÷Ä"Ä"Âóä"ÅBô"Ã2ó$Âòô"Âò÷ÂäÂæ£'ÄtróärôtwÆC"Ö2÷¢÷§Å
```

**Paper #4**

| Index from #1 | p | b | 2 | w | 9 | 5 | - | r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | q | i | i | t | v | 7 | q | i |
| o | i | j | l | n | 6 | w | 1 | 5 |
| r | p | 5 | o | t | h | q | 1 | l |
| 4 | q | h | m | 9 | q | l | 9 | u |
| d | q | g | 3 | c | l | h | 8 | g |
| i | q | c | m | y | q | b | e | d |
| - | z | x | y | e | b | r | 9 | h |
| 8 | q | b | 8 | c | y | s | w | v |
| 2 | d | i | b | p | c | 9 | p | f |

```
(21,22)(37,16)(15,19)(35,13) For #1
```

Can you help me find out the correct password?

---

**HINT**

> Search for Mozart's symphony No.35, "Haffner". And do what *"he"* did.

Comment: Nice - I like the question - I don't know that I would have given out all the hints so early though :)

Comment: To add on to what @Graylocke said, if you think hints are necessary to solve the puzzle, it's better to work those hints into the puzzle than to add them as hints later (of course, gauging whether or not the hints are needed to solve is easier said than done).

Comment: No, hints are not necessary. May I remove them? Only think some steps are too hard. Well I'll leave some hints, but remove the others.

Comment: You mention 5 papers in the backstory but the puzzle only shows 4 papers...

Comment: Only a typo @Sid

Comment: For all puzzle solvers: feel free to ask for hints, because this one is really a hard one. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I waited for really a long time but there's no response. So I decided to give the answer:

> **Answer:** arrest.

First look at paper #3, `´Ã£óEÕ´CDCE×Ç´BöB÷ÖBs"ÖBsróDBò÷Âä2æ2w§£2òô2ò÷Ä"Ä"Âóä"ÅBô"Ã2ó$Âòô"Âò÷ÂäÂæ£'ÄtróärôtwÆC"Ö2÷¢÷§Å`:

> Convert the characters into ASCII hex values: `b4c3a312f345d5b443444345d7c7b442f642f7d6427322d6427372f34442f2f7c2e432e63277a7a332f2f432f2f7c422c422c2f3e422c542f422c332f32412c2f2f422c2f2f7c2e412c2e617a327c47472f3e472f47477c64322d632f7a2f7a7c5`; then notice paper #2, 'he' moved the last character to the beginning. We do that: `5b4c3a312f345d5b443444345d7c7b442f642f7d6427322d6427372f34442f2f7c2e432e63277a7a332f2f432f2f7c422c422c2f3e422c542f422c332f32412c2f2f422c2f2f7c2e412c2e617a327c47472f3e472f47477c64322d632f7a2f7a7c`, then convert it back: `[L:1/4][D4D4]|{D/d/}d'2-d'7/4D//|.C.c'zz3//C//|B,B,/>B,T/B,3/2A,//B,//|.A,.az2|GG/>G/GG|d2-c/z/z|`. That's a piece of ABC notation. Convert it into score, and you'll get the beginning of Mozart's work, 'Haffner', which was composed in 1782.

Then paper #4, `(21,22)(37,16)(15,19)(35,13) For #1`.

> For each set `(ab,cd)`, we find the two letters in the keyboard grid in paper #1: 1. at ln `a`, col `b`; 2. at ln `c`, col `d`. You'll get `as my to be`. That's the clue for paper #1.

Then paper #1:

> For each word `xy` in `as my to be`, find the number at row `x`, col `y`. You'll get `0223`. Together with the year `1782` you get a date `1782.02.23`. James Watt's bidirectional steam engine was patented. So the inventor is `jameswatt`.

Finally, paper #4:

> The clues are `jameswatt` and `dangerous` (from the story). Turn every number `n` in the table into the `n`-th letter of `jameswatt`. Find for the letters `d a n g e r o u s`. They are on: 1. row p, col a; 2. row s, col s; 3. row w, col o; 4. row r, col d; 5. row -, col i; 6. row s, col -; 7. row a, col r; 8. row r, col e; 9. row s, col t. Combine them: `password-is-arrest`.

Comment: If you think one of your questions has been lacking an answer for too long, you can bring more attention to it by placing a [bounty](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on it (ideally with a new hint or two), in order to encourage more people to try it.